# Why am I able to read char[2] but not char[1]?

Tags: c++, oracle, types, char

I am able to read char into char[2] in [OCI C++](http://ocicpplib.sourceforge.net/) code, but I am not able to read to char[1](http://ocicpplib.sourceforge.net/)?

Does anyone have any idea why?

(oracle data type is char(1))

Comment: This kind of question will not get you a helpfull answer. Please elaborate on what you're trying to do, how you're doing it, and how it is failing.

Comment: Vague questions generate vague answers. Please re-edit your question and give some source code, some data examples and your unexpected outcome (e.g. Exception / Error / Unexpected behavour)

Answer (score 1):

If the input is being treated like a string, then room is needed to apply the null-termination (a `'\0'`) at the end. That is if the data is `'a'`, then the string representation (`"a"`) is stored in memory as two characters `'a'` and `'\0'`. The `'\0'` is needed to tell the usual string processing suspects where the string ends.

Without knowing anything about the tools you're using I can't say for sure, but you might be able to assign to a character variable (as opposed to a character array variable).

---

Looking briefly at the docs along the link you posted, I suspect that you should be using `std::string` as the receiving type for textual data.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you need space for the null character at the end of the string?